# Индексы в MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, индексация

Здравствуйте. Если кто может подсказать, был бы очень благодарен.

Есть такая схема документа:

```
{ 
    item_id:elm.id, 
    price:elm.price,
    location_id:elm.location_id, 
    category_id:elm.category_id, 
    prepay:elm.prepay, 
    is_auction:elm.is_auction, 
    user_id:elm.user_id, 
    keys:[], 
    attribute:[], 
    delivery:[], 
    payment:[] 
}
```

Описывающая каталог товаров. Так как `keys, attribute`... могут быть любые целые числа. Это ключи из MySQL. И параметры поиска тоже! Повесил ключи на все поля по отдельности, а так как сочетаний может быть много! Кто–то выбрал доставку конкретную, кто-то пользователя или вместе все, то при поиске решил вещать ключи на комбинацию!

Вопрос первый: как проверить добавлен такой именно индекс или нет? И при внесении повторно, база проверяет что уже есть такой? Или пересоздает его?

И главный вопрос: в коллекции 58 записей при выносе по пользователю и пределах стоимости и сортировке по цене (такой тестовый параметр поиска) скорость составляет 9ms, время не чистое! Это точный замер ответа сервера, но ошибки тут быть не может, все равно должен быть 0 или около нуля. Так как даже грубая сила на 58 записях дала бы сравнимый если не лучший результат. Сортировка тоже не может давать такую цифру, пересортировка менее 58 эл-тов массива скажем алгоритмом quicksort или грубой силой-это 0!

Как правильно вещать индексы в монге?

Answer (score 1):

Индексы не вешают на каждое из полей, в надежде, что один из них сработает. Дело в том, что при вставке данных требуется отсортировать индекс по-новой, чтобы новые данные им учитывались. Индексы ускоряют операции чтения, но замедляют операции вставки, обновления и удаления.

Индексируют конкретные запросы. У вас есть какой-то запрос, его и нужно индексировать. В запросе вероятно есть условие по нескольким полям - их и нужно включать в индекс. Допустим это поле `a` и `b`, индекс по этим двум полям пригодится в случае запросов, осуществляющих поиск по условиям с участием `a` и `b`, а также в случае запросов с участием только поля `a`. В запросах, с условием только по `b` такой индекс уже не поможет.

В любом случае индекс подбирается под конкретный запрос, как правило, самый популярный. Чем больше индексов - тем больше замедляются операции обновления данных.